# How to manage Azure Api Management CA Certificates through ARM templates

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-api-management

I'm trying to manage **CA certificates** in **Azure APIM** through **ARM** but everything I tried gave no positive result.

For visualization, this is what I'm talking about:
[image: CA Certificates in Azure Portal's APIM view]

When I look at the schema [Microsoft.ApiManagement/service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/2019-12-01/service?tabs=json), there's a section for certificates where I can set the **storeName** variable but without results.

> For sanity, I tried to upload it though Powershell plus manually and both option worked but that CA Certificate got wiped from the APIM at each deployment of my ARM template even if I used the "**Incremental**" option.

First I tried to modify the APIM ARM template by adding that block to the "properties" section:

```
"certificates": [
{
  "encodedCertificate": "[parameters('RootCertificateBase64Content')]",
  "certificatePassword": "[parameters('RootCertificatePassword')]",
  "storeName": "Root"
}]
```

Here's my first test snippet for complete traceability:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "apimName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the apimanagement"
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for all resources."
      }
    },
    "sku": {
      "type": "string",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Developer",
        "Standard",
        "Premium"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "Developer",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The pricing tier of this API Management service"
      }
    },
    "skuCapacity": {
      "type": "string",
      "allowedValues": [
        "1",
        "2"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "1",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The instance size of this API Management service."
      }
    },
    "subnetResourceId": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": ""
      }
    },
    "RootCertificateBase64Content": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The Root certificate content"
      }
    },
    "RootCertificatePassword": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The Root certificate password"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "publisherEmail": "whatever@heyho.com",
    "publisherName": "Whatever Team",
    "notificationSenderEmail": "whatever@heygo.com"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2019-12-01",
      "name": "[parameters('apimName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('sku')]",
        "capacity": "[parameters('skuCapacity')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "notificationSenderEmail": "[variables('notificationSenderEmail')]",
        "publisherEmail": "[variables('publisherEmail')]",
        "publisherName": "[variables('publisherName')]",
        "virtualNetworkConfiguration": {
          "subnetResourceId": "[parameters('subnetResourceId')]"
        },
        "virtualNetworkType": "Internal",
        "certificates": [
        {
          "encodedCertificate": "[parameters('RootCertificateBase64Content')]",
          "certificatePassword": "[parameters('RootCertificatePassword')]",
          "storeName": "Root"
        }]
      },
      "identity": {
        "type": "SystemAssigned"
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "apiManagementPrivateHostIp": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[reference(concat(resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service', parameters('apimName')))).privateIPAddresses[0]]"
    }
  }
}
```

Second alternative I tried was to use the [Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/2019-12-01/service/certificates?tabs=json) schema. There is no option there to specify the **StoreName** so I assumed it wasn't the right schema but I tried anyway. All attempts generated a certificate in the built-in **Certificates** store instead of the **CA Certificates** store.

Here's my second attempt's snippet:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "apimName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The parent APIM name"
      }
    },
    "certificateName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The certificate name"
      }
    },
    "CertificateBase64Content": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The content of the certificate"
      }
    },
    "CertificatePassword": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The certificate password"
      }
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[concat(parameters('apimName'), '/Root/', parameters('certificateName'))]",
      "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/certificates",
      "apiVersion": "2019-01-01",
      "properties": {
        "data": "[parameters('CertificateBase64Content')]",
        "password": "[parameters('CertificatePassword')]"
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

While looking at terraform documentation, it seems that it's possible to manage these certificates through the base schema and I confirmed that through the [terraform azurerm provider source code](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/0076813e26e12a50fde64ce8da910967d5786ddc/azurerm/internal/services/apimanagement/api_management_resource.go) (Unfortunately I cannot use Terraform and I MUST use ARM in that scenario).

Any clues on how to manage **CA certificates** in **Azure APIM** through **ARM**?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to update CA certificate authority sections of already existing APIM? If yes then just provide all required properties for `Microsoft.ApiManagement/service` but for name use already existing APIM name that you want to update and choose the same resource group.

Thanks to this, it will just update existing APIM with properties you provided, instead of creating new APIM. The required properties are `name`, `type`, `apiVersion`, `location`, `sku`, `properties`. For `properties` you need to provide `publisherEmail` and `publisherName`, and of course `certificates` - this is what you want to update after all. So the absolute minimum for update will look like this:

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters":{
  "base64EncodedCertificate":{
     "defaultValue":"base64 encoded certificate",
     "type":"String"
  },
  "certificatePassword":{
     "defaultValue":"certificate password",
     "type":"String"
  }
},
"variables": {},
"resources": [
    {
        "name": "existing-apim-name",
        "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service",
        "apiVersion": "2021-01-01-preview",
        "location": "West Europe",
        "sku": {
            "name": "Developer",
            "capacity": 1
        },
        "properties": {
            "publisherEmail": "publisher@gmail.com",
            "publisherName": "Publisher Name",
            "certificates": [
                {
                    "encodedCertificate": "[parameters('base64EncodedCertificate')]",
                    "certificatePassword": "[parameters('certificatePassword')]",
                    "storeName": "Root"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
}
```

**Watch out.** `certificates` array must contain all certificates that you want to have on this APIM. All existing CA certs that are not in this array will be deleted.

Comment: Thank you @SteppingRazor for your answer! Because every fields are parameterized I understand that my example could have been complexifying the analysis, but I assure you the values passed as parameters are always the same so I'm not recreating the APIM.

Comparing your answer with my first attempt, I cannot see what you did differently and what did make it work for you. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Félix Yes. And have you tried my example? This is the absolute minimum what you need to update certificates on APIM. Or maybe your base64encoded or password values are wrong?